# One-to-many relationship not working

Tags: php, laravel-4, relationship, eloquent

I've a one-to-many relationship with models

**Article**

```
class Article extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'articles';
    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('ArticleCategory');
    }
}
```

**ArticleCategory**

```
class ArticleCategory extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'articles_categories';
    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Article');
    }
}
```

In my controller I'm trying to grab all articles from a category

```
$categories = ArticleCategory::find(1);
$article = $categories->articles;
return $article;
```

and that works perfectly.

But when I’m trying to make an inverse

```
$article = Article::find(1);
$category = $article->categories;
return $category;
```

I'm getting `null`. I should get a category return for an article id in find().

> Database tabels:
>   - articles: Id | title | description | category_id
>   - articles_categories: Id | title

Comment: You have to use `with` when querying relationships

Comment: That's not correct. With just simply eager loads the relation. You probably want to inverse the definitions of your relationships. An article should have many ArticleCategories, and an ArticleCategory should belongTo an article.

Comment: I think that the only way to achieve both ends (**A**: display categories with articles in them, **B**: display articles with category name) is to apply a pivot table. I won't get articles list with categories (ex. "My awesome article title [category]") applying `with`.

Comment: @TryingTobemyself i've updated my question. I am using Laravel 4.1. I've read somewhere that in L4.1 i should use `whereHas` instead of `with`. Any advice about `whereHas` statement? Never used it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's *one to many* relationship you can easily do this

```
$category = ArticleCategory::find($article->category_id);
```

I think the error is in the naming in your database fields.
The field in your `articles` table which is pointing to the `articles_categories` should be name `articles_categories_id`.

Try this

```
public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('ArticleCategory','category_id');
}
```

Comment: with that i can only recieve for example "category name". But how can i recieve articles list **with** category name like: **First awesome article [here category name for that article]**, **Second awesome article [here category name for that article]**, ... and so on. That'a a problem i'm fighting for a few days now.

Comment: Maybe this will clarify more. When i make **$articles = Article::orderBy('id', 'DESC')->paginate(10);** and in my blade in foreach loop **{{ $article->title }} {{ $article->category_id }}** i recieve all articles in descending order displaying also category id like: **Third Article [2]**, **Second article [5]**, **First article [3]**. But instead of id's (2, 5 and 3) i'd like to display a category name.

Comment: @SONGE Check eager loading http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading. Or create a custom query for your needs. But this is a different question. You said you couldn't receive categories at all.